# Stating variables in the onClick attribute, and using multiple commands in onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick

Alrighty then. Before I get started, I did search for this, I realize there are other threads on this topic, but none of them answered my question well.

So what I am trying to do is when a tag is clicked, it creates a variable inside of the onClick attribute that can be accessed from a function to be used with a case switch.

1) Can variables be created in the onClick attribute?
2) Can multiple commands be executed in the onClick attribute? Like : `onClick="alert('Boo!'); afunction();"`?

I apologize for the lack of code, but I am using an apple iPad, and they don't use the tab button or indents, blah blah.. Heres what I tried:

```
[..omitted..]
var item = "null";
function executeFunction(){
    switch(item){
    case "item1":
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display='none';
        break;
    case "item1":
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display='none';
        break;
    case "item2":
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display='none';
        break;
    case "item3":
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display=block';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display='none';
        break;
    case "item4":
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display='block';
        break;
    }
}

</script>
<ul>
    <li onClick="item = 'item1'; executeFunction();">Some item</li>
    <li onClick="item = 'item2'; executeFunction();">Some other item</li>
    <li onClick="item = 'item3'; executeFunction();">Some flying reptile</li>
    <li onClick="item = 'item4'; executeFunction();">Some psilocin</li>
</ul>
[..omitted..]
```

Comment: You need to show some code and describe what you are trying to do better.  I think I understand, but before I answer what I believe you have asked, I'd really like to know what you really need.

Comment: There's a simplified versions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first multiple commands can be used, separated by semicolons; However, it is generally not recommended ... you might try creating a master function or a series of them so that only one function has to be mentioned in the HTML code.

Then, you don't need to create the variables ... try this

```
<li onClick="executeFunction('item1');">Some item</li>
```

... then, the `executeFunction` would be like this ...

```
function executeFunction(item) {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display='none';
  document.getElementById("div2").style.display='none';
  document.getElementById("div3").style.display='none';
  document.getElementById("div4").style.display='none';

  switch(item){
    case "item1":
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display='block';
      break;
    case "item2":
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display='block';
      break;
    case "item3":
      document.getElementById("div3").style.display='block';
      break;
    case "item4":
      document.getElementById("div4").style.display='block';
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do: onClick="var='X'; doThis()".

Answer (score 1):

Separate the javascript commands in the onClick with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
 onclick="varname = value"
```